# Bison, simple calculator program

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I want to make parser for simple calculator but I cant uderstand whu I get error for simple input.
Flex file looks like this

```
%{
#include "exp.tab.h"
#include <string.h>
%}

blanks          [ \t\n]+


%%

{blanks}        { /* ignore */ }
[0-9]+           {yylval= strtol(yytext, NULL, 10);
return(NUMB);}

%%
```

Bison file looks like this:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}


%token NUMB


%left '+'


%%

exp:
NUMB                { $$ = $1;           }
| exp '+' exp        { $$ = $1 + $3;      }

%%
int yyerror(char *s) {
printf("yyerror : %s\n",s);
}

int main(void) {
yyparse();
}
```

For input

```
123 + 12
```

i get error message.Why is this happening?

Comment: Be aware when tagging.  Flex is used for the Adobe/Apache Framework.  Gnu-flex is used for the lexical analyzer.

Comment: @Reboog711, `flex-lexer` is, actually...

Comment: @Charles Thanks; I had no idea.  I just modified the "Flex Tag Wiki" to make mention of the flex-lexer tag: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/flex/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lexer is missing a rule to match/return the `'+'` token.  Try adding at the end:

```
.    { return *yytext; }  /* any other single character returns as itself */
```

The default lexer action if the text doesn't match any rule is to print it and skip it.  So they error you get from the parser is because it gets `123 12` as the input, which causes a syntax error.